# Where is PHP's spl_autoload_register only called and why is it better than include?

Tags: php, class

Does it go at the top of each .php file that references a given class?
When would I not want to use `spl_autoload_register()`?

I saw one question on SO that asked about the benefit.  I wasn't sure it answered my question.

If I have a .php file and it has ten includes.  That's ten lines.  That doesn't sound bad when I look at this from [here](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md):

```
<?php

function autoload($className)
{
    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $fileName  = '';
    $namespace = '';
    if ($lastNsPos = strrpos($className, '\\')) {
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';

    require $fileName;
}
```

Is it because some PHP programs have fifty classes and the naming convention makes it easy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include means you must do the work of specifying what files to load. You might include a file, for instance, when it is procedural and outside your class structure.

Autoload means you have a function that will load the files for you as you need them. When combined with namespaces and files that match the file paths, it is a very powerful tool.

For instance, you can create `\My\Namespace\Class` inside `/my/namespace/class.php` and autoloader will load that fule when you do something like this

```
$class = new \My\Namespace\Class();
```

Comment: Do I put the autoloader function at the top of each .php file that will call a class?

Comment: Yes, each file has to have it. Generally speaking, you'll probably have a single include that sets that up for you so you can just call that one file (common called a [bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752091/php-bootstrap-php)). Autoloading will take care of the rest.

Comment: Solaiman is saying something different, I thought.  So each individual .php file needs some sort of include.  Won't that load everything I need and don't need?

Comment: If you look at the last line of the function you posted, it's doing `require`, which is the same thing as include. Sooner or later you have to bring the file in. Sol is saying you don't need to include the class file directly. But you do have include your autoloader declaration at the top of all pages.

Answer (score 1):

No, it shouldn't be at the top  of each .php class file,  you have to include it it at  point when the app started.

it look like an observer for new instantiated classes if the  class file not included, then the autloader function  will include it to make the class available, this will save a lot of consumed time while including  HARD CODED files.

so if you've instatiated a class like new \MyNameSpace\CustomClass, the autoloader will look to folder /MyNameSpace/CustomClass.php and include it

Comment: Ok.  That makes more sense.  So I have an index.php, for example, I do the autoload and that's it?  Now any php page in this application and simply reference it $some_class = new TheClass();  EDIT:  I'm not sure I understand.  Are you saying I only put it in my very first loaded .php page, "index.php" or whatever?

Comment: Yes and that's it :-) ...

Comment: That is not what @Machavity is saying.  Do I misunderstand you both?

Comment: Ok, to be more clear, @Machavity said that  you can  call it one time in a file commonly called bootstrap, so if all requests  to your applications comes through index.php so the index will be the bootstrap or just create a file called bootstrap.php and include in the index.php